# User name availability check not connecting

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I found a free script for username validation on the interwebs, This is the javascript side of it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#username").blur(function () {
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
        //check the username exists or not from ajax
        $.post("availability.php", {
            user_name: $(this).val()
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == 'no') //if username not avaiable
            {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function () //start fading the messagebox
                {
                    $(this).html('This User name Already exists').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1);
                });
            } else {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function () //start fading the messagebox
                {
                    $(this).html('Username available to register').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1);
                });
            }

        });    
    });

});
```

You see this references the page "availibility.php" that code is as follows:

```
<?

$existing_users=array('roshan','mike','jason'); 


$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];


if (in_array($user_name, $existing_users))

{


echo "no";

} 

else

{

//user name is available

echo "yes";

}

?>
```

And then finally, on the page, this is the input tag that the user enters data in:

```
<input name="user_name" type="text" id="username" value="" maxlength="15" />
     <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
```

I have this script using the latest version of jquery (1.4.4)
this is the link to a working example: [Link](http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/username-available/)

When you type in "mike" in my website, it says that the username is available for use. In the example link I provided above, the username is taken, like it should be.

The only possible issue I can think of is maybe my host does not provide support for ajax? 
Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always use tools like firebug to inspect what's going on during the ajax stuff. Also modern browsers like Safari or Chrome do have web developer tools built-in.

Comment: All hosts provide AJAX support. AJAX is nothing else than regular HTTP requests. The only difference is how this request is handled at the client side.

Comment: @elusive - That isn't *quite* true in all cases, some platforms handle them explicitly differently, like CakePHP and controllers.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Right, but that is on a higher level. I thought he was talking about webservers (correct me if i am wrong).

Comment: @elusive The difference is that the HTTP response is handled by the XHR object (rather then the browser itself). The request is handled by the server.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I know that the client handles it differently (XHR, ActiveX, etc.), but the OP is clearly talking about hosts, not clients. AJAX-requests use HTTP(S) as well, so there is absolutely no difference to regular requests (server-side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the response in firebug, chrome, etc...whatever you're using, my guess would be that `"no"` isn't the *only* thing being echoed in the response, you can do a simple `alert(data)` at the top of your success handler in `$.post()` to see what else may be in there.  Make sure *only* what you want is echoed in the response.

Comment: Ah, you were right, after doing an alert, I got this in response:

no
<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="webhosting"/></noscript>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code-->

How can I filter this analytics code from my host out?

Comment: @Ryan - looks like something your host is adding in there...maybe they have instructions on how to bypass it for AJAX requests?

Comment: Thats exactly what it was, I disabled it and everything is working fine. Thank you for providing the alert() tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here is best script for username availability checker in php mysql jquery Ajax
get it from here http://www.my-php-scripts.net/index.php/Jquery/ajax-username-availability.html